# I have a KVP Key value pair Table, Need sql to make it relational structure...!

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a KVP Table and the structure is ID, Key, Value.

Here are some example values...

```
ID, KEY,       VALUE
---------------------
 1, STATUS,    TRUE
 1, AGE GROUP, 10
 1, TRAVEL,    Y
 2, STATUS,    FALSE
 2, AGE GROUP, 20
 2, TRAVEL,    N
```

I want these values to be transformed as below...

```
ID, STATUS, AGE GROUP, TRAVEL
------------------------------
 1, TRUE,   10,        Y
 2, FALSE,  20,        N
```

I have read about crosstab/pivot, but I'm not able to make a query which can give me the above output. Is there any way in SQL to make my output look like the above example?

Comment: Are the columns, ID , STATUS, AGE GROUP, TRAVEL are always fixed or they are dynamic .... If they are dynamic then we have to go with dynamic sql which will be slow ....

Comment: Ya its dynamic, but i have an option to construct from java and execute the query...

Comment: What SQL system are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the query. I am using Oracle. I think with this answer i am kind of close. For example if ID 2 does not have any travel information - i need nulls. Just tweaked the query with LEFT JOIN. Is it fine or should i avoid using left join ?

Comment: I used " full join " to get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably optimizations, but this works (tested in SQLite and MySQL)

```
select stat.id as id, status, age_group, travel from 
(select id, Value as status from kvp
where Key = 'STATUS') as stat JOIN
(select id, Value as age_group from kvp
where Key = 'AGE GROUP') as age on stat.id = age.id JOIN
(select id, Value as travel from kvp
where Key = 'TRAVEL') as trav on stat.id = trav.id;
```

Edited to fix a possible ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming Oracle based on the tag, then

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
  , MAX(CASE key WHEN 'STATUS' THEN value ELSE null END) OVER (PARTITION BY id) status
  , MAX(CASE key WHEN 'AGE GROUP' THEN value ELSE null END) OVER (PARTITION BY id) age_grp
  , MAX(CASE key WHEN 'TRAVEL' THEN value ELSE null END) OVER (PARTITION BY id) travel
FROM kvp
ORDER BY id;
```

Comment: Thanks this worked...but it has CASE, PARTITION ,etc,. I wanted a pure sql.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    min(decode(KEY, 'ID',        VALUE, null)) ID,
    min(decode(KEY, 'STATUS',    VALUE, null)) STATUS,
    min(decode(KEY, 'AGE GROUP', VALUE, null)) AGE_GROUP,
    min(decode(KEY, 'TRAVEL',    VALUE, null)) TRAVEL
from
    KVP
```